# Implementing an ExceptionListener on a MessageListener

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq, jboss-eap-6

Our structure is the following:
BaseQueue -> Message gets copied in copy queue (This is where we read from)

Connection to the Queuemanager / Queue is done via wmq.jmsra.rar resource adapter.

So I just want to read messages from a queue. I do not want to send any reply back.

Therefore I implemented a MessageListener and configured the queue through the ejb-jar.xml file.

This is all working fine but now I want to implement an ExceptionListener to handle connection losses, etc.

I thought it would be fine to just implement the ExceptionListener interface like this:

```
public class MdB implements MessageListener, ExceptionListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
         ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
         ...
    }
}
```

But it seems this is not enough as the onException method never gets called from the resource-adapter.

Can anyone help me out? Maybe it would be enough to get the connection the resource adapter uses and set the exception listener for this object but I couldn't find a way to obtain the connection object.

Thanks

Comment: Have you fixed problem

Answer (score 0):

You also need to register the exception listener with the connection by calling `setExceptionListener` on the connection object.

```
connection.setExceptionListener(this); // class implementing the ExceptionListener interface
```

**Additional Reading**

- [JMS ExceptionListener in WebSphere MQ](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21314744)

Comment: "Can anyone help me out? Maybe it would be enough to get the connection the resource adapter uses and set the exception listener for this object but I couldn't find a way to obtain the connection object"

Do you know how to obtain the connection object? It is managed by the resource adapter itself.